# How can I best determine the Signal/Noise of a pulsed signal?

Tags: signal-detection

I have this pulsed signal, and I would like to quantify the signal to noise ratio. Is there a preferred way to do this? My current approach is to filter the points that are obviously part of the background noise, and find their deviation value. That's my noise value. My signal value is the average of the max peak values. I then find the ratio between these two.

I feel like this approach is wrong and I'm wondering what is the best way to do this? [image: Pulsed signal]

Edit: I also feel like signal/noise might not be the correct measurement, it seems something like signal strength / background noise.

Comment: You say you want to measure SNR, but then that you're not sure whether this is the correct measurement. What's your actual goal--what do you want to know about the measured signal?

Comment: I want to quantify the strength of the peak values compared to the strength of the noise. This is something that someone requested I do for my data. They mentioned SNR, but I have a feeling they might have been mistaken.